# Car wiring: piggybacking DC down a speaker wire

Tags: voltage

So, I have a Japanese import car without a rear foglight, and I need to install one in order to pass the UK MOT (roadworthiness) test. Properly installing and routing the wiring for the foglight would mean stripping out a lot of the interior of the vehicle, which will take a long time and is something I’d rather not do.

Now, the car does have speaker wiring running from behind the dashboard (right near where I’d want to install the foglight switch) all the way into the tailgate (where I’d want to install the light itself, in place of one of the reversing lamps).

The speaker is driven by an AC signal, whereas the foglight is 12v DC. Is there any reason why I couldn’t make use of one of the speaker wires to carry power to my foglight, installing a capacitor of suitable value to stop any DC from reaching the speaker?  I appreciate that the AC signal will be elevated by 12v when the foglight is switched on, but will the cap remove that elevation when it blocks the DC, or not?

Is there any reason why this won’t work, or shouldn’t be done?

Comment: one helluva pop in the speaker when you switch the fog light on or off, it might even trash  the amplifier output.

Comment: Do people actually drive in reverse in the fog? 

Comment: @Marla - Do you know of an efficient method of parking that doesn't involve it? (I can't think of one)

Comment: @enhzflep. . Didn't know fog could get so thick in the UK (small distance to move slightly in reverse to park)

Comment: Possible.  Best to have two capacitors (one to block DC from feeding into the amplifier and one to block DC from the speaker).  Have to be quite large and unpolarized capacitors as well.   Problem is audio needs to go down to about 20-40Hz, which is not far from DC in the grand scheme of the universe  (hence REALLY BIG caps needed)   I suggest strongly don't monkey with it, just figure how to run a new wire.  It's not as hard as you think.   Usually you can lift the trim from around the doors and slip it behind the carpeting.

Comment: Can you use the existing backup-lamp and put your foglight in parallel with it???   So when you backup, the foglight turns on?  Or does the law require a separate switch?????

Comment: @KyleB and others: A rear fog light (a red rear-facing light brighter than the normal red tail lights) is used when driving forwards in fog. So it can't be run in parallel with the reversing light.

Comment: @Marla They have to drive backward since they're on the wrong side of the road.

Comment: I am not familiar with your laws or your vehicle. I know a chap that works for a wire harness maker.  He told me many times a harness will have wiring for an option that is not installed because it is more cost effective to use one harness for several vehicles then keep two or more harnesses in stock. You might have one.  If it must be on all the time you could possibly power it with the tail light circuit, using LEDs to keep the power down.

Comment: The MoT only says it has to work, it doesn't have to look pretty. Just rig it up as best you can until you get the time to do it neatly.

Comment: @Gil The wiring for a factory version foglight is present, but on this particular vehicle fitting one would mean fitting (and painting) a new rear quarter panel, dismantling the dash to fit a new control stalk, and spending ~£750 on parts.

Comment: Here in North America we also have fog but no rear fog lights. A red light at the back of a vehicle has its brakes turned on. If a person from here drives in the fog in the UK or a UK person drives in the fog here then they will probably be in many collisions.

Answer (score 1):

To put DC on the speaker leads, you would not only have to block the DC from going into the speakers and amplifier, you would also have to block the audio from going into the DC power source.

A battery generally has a very low impedance, to audio frequencies it's going to be close to a short circuit. You would need some way to keep it from loading down the audio signal, usually you would do this with some sort of inductor.
One possibility would be transformer coupling. Put a center tapped audio transformer large enough to handle the audio power plus the DC power at each end of the speaker cables, connect the positive DC voltage to the center taps and use the vehicle chassis as the return.

The transformers solve both the problem of blocking the DC from the speaker and amp, and blocking the audio from the DC supply. Since the DC is on both speaker leads and therefore common-mode, it should also reduce any popping when the light is switched on.

Since there would be high current DC available on the speaker leads you would need to fuse the circuit appropriately.

You also have to take into account core saturation from the DC current. You would want to use as little DC current as possible, an LED lamp would be the best choice, an LED rear fog lamp will draw somewhere around 200 mA, you would have to make sure the transformers could handle this plus the audio without saturating.

Running a wire is still your best option, tracking down appropriate transformers may be difficult and almost certainly expensive. I mainly offered this suggestion to point out the problem with using capacitors.

[image: schematic]

<sup>[simulate this circuit](/plugins/schematics?image=http%3a%2f%2fi.stack.imgur.com%2fvEZgB.png) – Schematic created using [CircuitLab](https://www.circuitlab.com/)</sup>

Comment: while your proposed solution look great on paper, practically speaking it would require some quite bit transformers for a Fog Lamp require some substantial current that could easily magnetically saturate both transformer and provoke a "short" on the amplifier output. The speaker sound volume would drastically go lower and the amplifier could even get damaged. I do not endorse this contraction.

Comment: @FredCailloux I wonder how much of a problem that would be. With the center tap, would the effect of the DC currents on the core cancel? Transformers with DC current going through them have been used for a century in push-pull amplifiers, so it must be possible.  I'm not finding much information online about how much DC current audio transformers can handle.

Comment: I see your point. While it is true that many power amps of the past were using Push-Pull configuration with transformers, these amps were power hungry and dissipated lots of heat, but another disadvantage  with this contraption is the frequency response. We have little information about the quality of this audio system but chances are that nowadays car audio are of much better performance than when audio transformers were in use. But your solution is certainly feasible considering an adequate size transformer. You changed my mind. Its a better solution than no solution. :)

Answer (score 0):

> in order to pass the UK MOT (roadworthiness) test.

If all you care about is pass that test, just disconnect your speakers and utilize those wires for the test purpose. Then disconnect those totally useless fog-lights and reconnect your speakers, enjoying music for the rest of the car life.

I can hardly imagine an agent going through the hassle of testing your fog-lights in the future.

By the way, are those speaker wires of adequate gauge ?  Fog-lights current requirement is far higher than speakers.  Just make sure that those wires do not melt when power is switched ON .

Comment: I probably could connect and disconnect it annually (the test is carried out annually) but I'd rather go with a 'fit and forget' solution if possible.

Comment: The MOT test is repeated yearly.

Comment: An incandescent fog lamp bulb is typically 12V 21W, it would have to be extremely thin speaker wiring to have a problem carrying that.

Comment: If something is required to pass an MOT it's required all the time. Disconnecting lights after a test is illegal. Also keeping the car roadworthy is usually an insurance requirement. In practice it's not likely to be spotted unless OP has an accident after which it's bumper prosecution time - unroadworthy vehicle and driving without insurance. Plus no insurance payout.